# Gradle productFlavors raises error - Cannot add task ':assembleTest' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

New to Gradle, trying to create build variants. I just added a productFlavor to the gradle file all of a sudden I get this strange error

```
$ gradle tasks
Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "srcDirs" on "source set aild", value: "[src]".

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'SegmentIO'.
> Cannot add task ':assembleTest' as a task with that name already exists.
```

Here is my complete build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'


dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"
    compileSdkVersion 17

    productFlavors {
        test {
        }

        prod {
        }
    }

     sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src', 'bundled-src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aild.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }

        // test.assets.srcDirs = ['$java-project-root/assets/test']
        // prod.assets.srcDirs = ['$java-project-root/assets/test']

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: './libs', include: 'Amplitude.jar')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems:

```
Deprecated dynamic property: "srcDirs" on "source set aild", value: "[src]".
```

is because you misspelled `aild.srcDirs` in your build file -- it should be `aidl.srcDirs`.

```
> Cannot add task ':assembleTest' as a task with that name already exists.
```

is because you're trying to create a flavor named "test", but this is being used by something else in the build and it's colliding. Try using a different name.

To be more specific, the Android plugin makes a number of tasks based off the flavor name (it does this with build types, too). If you have a flavor name "foo", **assembleFoo** performs an **assemble** but only on the **foo** flavor. There's already an **assembleTest** task, so it's colliding when it tries to make one for your flavor.

Comment: Thanks - yes the flavor name 'test' was the issue

Comment: Is there any way to override its naming scheme?

Comment: @CasualT I don't think so.

Comment: thanks. :)  I might open a new question then. I'm in this weird space where I want to have different flavors based on referencing a maven artifact and referencing a local module, but that local module collides with the the artifact.